# How to write relative path?

Tags: html, css, path

I have two folders. One called app, which contains index.html, sass, img. And second build with folders: css, js. What path should I type in index.html to access the style.css file, which is in build/css/style.css ? I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href"build/css/style.css">
```

Comment: your `css` and `js` folders should be in same directory as the **app** where index.html is then try `css/style.css`

Comment: darg the file to index file and the link write automaticlly

Comment: here explain:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your **css** and **js** folders should be in same directory as the **app** where `index.html` is then try `css/style.css`

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So **app**, which contains index.html, sass, img , should now also contain js and css folder. Then it should definitely work.

If keeping the file directory as is, you should understand.

*Starting with `/` returns to the root directory and starts there then `../` moves one directory backwards and starts there and so on `../../`. In that case 
`<link href="../build/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your **html file:-**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your both folder 'app' and 'build' are siblings then use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../build/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change it become

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href"../build/css/style.css">
```

Your index.html is on "app" folder and the css is on "another folder" which have the same path with "app" folder. So you need to get out from the "app" folder first with "../" then redirect it into your destination folder. If you need to get out from current folder you're in twice it'll be like "../../your/destination/folder" and coulde be more.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="picture.jpg">
```

picture.jpg is located in the same folder as the current page

```
<img src="images/picture.jpg">
```

picture.jpg is located in the images folder in the current folder

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg">
```

picture.jpg is located in the images folder at the root of the current web

```
<img src="../picture.jpg">
```

picture.jpg is located in the folder one level up from the current folder

Answer (score 0):

Relative path is **relative** to the file where you put the reference. Here in your case, **style.css** is in **build/** folder which is next to **app** folder that covers **index.html**. So if you want to make a reference to style.css from within index.html, usually you should use the relative path **../build/css/style.css**.

But make sure the css file is really reachable. It depends on whether you are using a web server, what web server you are using, and what is the starting point from which you run your project.

If you simply open **index.html** by clicking the file from file explorer, then you can use this to make style.css work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/css/style.css">
```

However the above method is not recommended. Normally you will want to make use of a web server to serve such static files like js, css.

I would recommend you to try [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) which is a light weighted web server let allow you to do local development and checkout what you've been done immediately by visiting something like http://localhost:8000.

When you are using a web server to serve static files, make sure you start running it with a starting point that already covers **app** and **build** folders (such that all of the files you want are reachable), for instance, with the parent folder of those 2 folders. If so, when you want to open **index.html**, you are going to visit something like http://localhost:8000/app/index.html (Because index.html lies under app/ folder, you need to add the "app/"). When this layout is applied, you have at lease 2 ways to insert the css lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../build/css/style.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/build/css/style.css">
```

What if you don't want to add the "app/" while visiting index.html? Then you could move index.html out of app folder, right into the project starting point. That way whenever you go to http://localhost:8000, usually index.html is assumed to be served. (Just like visiting http://localhost:8000/index.html). When you are using that method to run your project, the reference to style.css is just the way you were doing, which is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="build/css/style.css">
```

By the way, this is also perfectly fine in that case, with an absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/build/css/style.css">
```

Things will go different if you are using other mechanisms to serve static files like css, js. But the core principle is that simple: make sure files you want can be reached, and the relative path you are using really reveals the path relation between the reference point and the target referenced file.